# How to update Symfony Entities from an existing database?

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, fosuserbundle

I found in Symfony docs [that](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)  you can Generate Entities from an Existing Database so are there any ways to update entities from existing database I added using MySQL?

For example, I added new column to my FOSUSERBUNDLE database called "batman"

using this command on MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE cs_symfony_members
ADD batman int(11) NOT NULL;
```

how to update my entities i generated using the docs guide above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update database schema to Entity, you can use two command:

(1) Create entity mapping from database:

```
bin/console doctrine:mapping:import BundleName --filter=EntityName
```

(2) Update your entity to match this mapping:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName:EntityName
```

Example, I have a User table in database, a had changed structure of this table. And now, I want to update these changes to my User entity in AppBundle. I need to run following command:

```
bin/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle --filter=User
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:User
```

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is having trouble finding this command after forgetting, like me, here it is:

When i update my Entities from my already existing sql database, I juste use this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle annotation --filter="Entity name".
```

I'm using symfony 3.4 but I'm gussing this also works for later versions.